# What does this for mean?

Tags: java

The following code let me access the elements of the IterableItem, that is a List of CmisObject objects

```
ItemIterable<CmisObject> iterable=session.getRootFolder().getChildren();

    for (CmisObject o : iterable) {
        System.out.println(o.getName() + " which is of type " + o.getType().getDisplayName());
    }
```

What is the meaning of the for?

EDIT: It is a strange implementation of an iterable interface... Why am i not able to iterate it with something like this?

```
        while(iterable.getHasMoreItems())
    {
        CmisObject o=iterable......?
    }
```

Why does the for works why i am not able to do it with this while?

Comment: its a foreach.  For each CmisObject o in iterable

Comment: The meaning of the for? Search for loops..

Comment: "*Why am I not able to iterate it with something like this...*" you need to realize that `Iterable` and `Iterator` is not the same. `Iterable` can return `Iterator` which can be later used in loop.

Comment: Can you please post a complete answer? Why should the for be able to do this just with a foreach, while i have to get a Iterable, and then get a Iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for in this context uses the Iterator. 'Enhanced For-Loop' (Also known as foreach).

Any class implementing iterable ([JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)) returns an iterator you may use like that:

```
final Iterator<MyClass> it = iterable.iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {
   MyClass instance = it.next();
   // ...
}
```

Or you may choose to use for:

```
for(MyClass m:iterable) {
  // ... 
}
```

You may use this on Arrays aswell.

Answer (score 2):

It's an for-each loop. It is used to iterate over all items of an Iterable (such as your List of CmisObject) or Arrays.

See [foreach explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)